# Run a background task in a SINGLE gofiber process

Tags: go, go-fiber

I have a background task (`cleanUp`) that deletes outdated files.

```golang
func main() {
    // 4 procs/childs max
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    // start a cleanup cron-job
    go cleanUp()

    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Prefork:   true,
    })
    app.Post("/", handleFileupload)
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":4000"))
}

func cleanUp() {
    fmt.Println("Cleaning Up..")
    for {
        // deletes old files here
        time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

At the moment `cleanUp` runs on all 4 processes and prints `Cleaning Up..` 4 times.

But I want it to run only on a single process and print a single `Cleaning Up..`. I have tried waitGroups and channels but failed to achieve what I wanted.

How can I run it only on a single process to avoid race conditions?

Here is the output:

```
Cleaning Up..

 ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                   Fiber v2.38.1                   │  │ Child PIDs ... 79378, 79379, 79380, 79381         │
 │               http://127.0.0.1:4000               │  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 │       (bound on host 0.0.0.0 and port 4000)       │ 
 │                                                   │ 
 │ Handlers ............. 5  Processes ........... 4 │ 
 │ Prefork ........ Enabled  PID ............. 79377 │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

Cleaning Up..
Cleaning Up..
Cleaning Up..
Cleaning Up..
```

Comment: What "threads" are we talking about here? You start a single `cleanUp` goroutine, which runs _once_. Are you running the same process multiple times?

Comment: Threads that I created with `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)`. No, it runs 4 times.

Comment: If it runs 4 times, it is because you are executing it 4 times. The example shown here, regardless of `GOMAXPROCS`, will execute the `cleanUp` function one time. Are you certain you are not executing this code in multiple _processes_?

Comment: I guess so. I just build and run the executable.

Comment: It looks like the `fiber` package is abusing GOMAXPROCS as a value to start that number of processes, or there is some other config you are not showing here. A quick google also shows that they provide a [`fiber.IsChild`](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/fiber#ischild) function to detect which process you are in.

Comment: omg, sorry.. may be this has smth to do with: `Prefork:   true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiber spawns several processes to handle incoming requests. What you need is launch the cleanup routine in the master process and skip it in the child processes.

Fiber provides [`fiber.IsChild`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2#IsChild) function:

```golang
    // start a cleanup cron-job
    if !fiber.IsChild() {
        go cleanUp()
    }
```

I slightly modified your example to print process ID in the handler and the cleanup goroutine:

```
func main() {
    // 4 procs/childs max
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    // start a cleanup cron-job
    if !fiber.IsChild() {
        go cleanUp()
    }

    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Prefork: true,
    })
    app.Post("/", handleFileupload)
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":4000"))
}

func cleanUp() {
    fmt.Println("Cleaning Up.. Pid:", syscall.Getpid())
    for {
        // deletes old files here
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Cleaning Up.. Pid:", syscall.Getpid())
    }
}

func handleFileupload(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    println("Upload: pid ", syscall.Getpid())
    return nil
}
```

Result:

```
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035

 ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                   Fiber v2.39.0                   │  │ Child PIDs ... 27041, 27042, 27044, 27045         │
 │               http://127.0.0.1:4000               │  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 │       (bound on host 0.0.0.0 and port 4000)       │ 
 │                                                   │ 
 │ Handlers ............. 1  Processes ........... 4 │ 
 │ Prefork ........ Enabled  PID ............. 27035 │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 

Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
Cleaning Up.. Pid: 27035
```

As you see, cleanup runs in the master process only.